# Solving for limit of natural log function

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

> Trying to solve the following:
> $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{4\ln(x)+2\ln(x^3)}{\ln(x)-\ln(\sqrt{x})}$.

Progress so far:

$\frac{4\ln(x)+6\ln(x)}{\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)}$

Not sure where I am supposed to go from here though... if I follow limit laws as I know them, I get $\frac{0}{0}$ which I don't think is what I want. The graph of this function is a horizontal line at $20$, which at $x=1$ is undefined.

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: $ln(x)$ cancels (except $x=1$), so expression $=20$ otherwise.  Therefore the limit is $20$.

Answer (score 2):

Proceeding from where you got,
$$
\require{cancel}\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{4\ln x+6\ln x}{\frac{1}{2}\ln x}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{10\bcancel{\ln x}}{\dfrac{1}{2}\bcancel\ln x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{10}{1/2}=\color{green}{20}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. Here is a hint : Use L'Hopital's Rule. ($\frac{0}{0}$ Indeterminate)